# How to find the beginning of a string value in a table with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out how the solve the following case:

I have a list of numbers in a table, for example:

```
223
5533
81
816
```

Now I have a request which should search for the right number/s in the table. A number in the request can (for example) look like one of the following:

```
223
2234
22367
55332
```

Now I am trying to find the right `where`-Clause in Laravel Eloquent to fetch the right "wildcard" numbers.

The mentioned `$requestNumber`s should lead to the following query results:

`$requestNumber = 223`
=> `223`

`$requestNumber = 2234`
=> `223` and `22367`.

`$requestNumber = 55332`
=> `5533`.

`$requestNumber = 816349` 
=> `81` and `816`

In my understanding it should be the opposite of the following `like` query:

```
Number::where('number', 'like', $requestNumber. '%')->get();
```

I need the "twisted" way (I know it's not possible like that):

```
Number::where('number' . %, 'like', $requestNumber)->get();
```

Comment: @CBroe I edited my question to make it more clear what the query results should look like. In your example the result should only be `223`.

Comment: You would need to CONCAT the content of the `number` column and the text literal `'%'` here … but don’t ask me how to press that into Laravel’s query builder syntax.

Comment: Guess a syntax similar to what’s shown here should probably do the trick, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845630/1427878, involving `DB::raw` is probably the main part to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cbroe's comment I was able to create the needed query to achieve what I am looking for:

```
Number::where(DB::raw('"' . $requestNumber . '"'), 'like', DB::raw('concat(number, "%")'));
```