# Search users by fullname in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to search users by fullname so i need to concat two columns which are first_name and last_name and look if it matches the given value or not, this is my try

```
$users = User::where(function($usersSearchQuery) use ($user,$fullName){
$usersSearchQuery
->whereNotIn('id', $user->blockerUsers->pluck('blocked_id'))
->whereNotIn('id', $user->blockedUsers->pluck('blocker_id'))
->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE \''.$fullName.'\'%'); })->get();
```

i have an error in this line

```
->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE  \''.$fullName.'\'%');
```

> message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where (1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE 'BertHue'%))"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845630/7964905 check this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$users = User::where(function($usersSearchQuery) use ($user,$fullName){
            $usersSearchQuery->whereNotIn('id', $user->blockerUsers->pluck('blocked_id'))
            ->whereNotIn('id', $user->blockedUsers->pluck('blocker_id'))
            ->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE \''.$fullName.'%\'');
        })->get();
```

I replaced your last `where` with a `whereRaw` which allows you to use raw SQL.

Comment: i  just tried your code i got this error : message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where (1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE 'BertHue'%))"

Comment: I have edited my answer, there was a typo in the `whereRaw` clause. Tell me if it works,  you shouln't have anymore error.